# HTML text area always appearing in new line

Tags: html, css

The below code is a statement having two text area fields. But it is not appearing as a single line. The components are always written in a new line.

```
<TD width="100%" class=DataLeftAligned id=td_0_0 colSpan=8 name="td_0_0">SIGNED COMMERCIAL INVOICE IN <TEXTAREA name=text1_0_0 disabled id=text1_0_0 style="OVERFLOW: auto; WORD-WRAP: break-word; OVERFLOW-Y: auto; PADDING-BOTTOM: 0px; PADDING-TOP: 0px; PADDING-LEFT: 0px; MARGIN: 0px; DISPLAY: block; PADDING-RIGHT: 0px" onkeydown=limitTextArea(this,100,65); onkeyup=limitTextArea(this,100,65); rows=1 cols=3></TEXTAREA>_TI_3 COPIES INDICATING THIS CREDIT NUMBER.AND <TEXTAREA name=text2_0_0 disabled id=text2_0_0 style="OVERFLOW: auto; WORD-WRAP: break-word; OVERFLOW-Y: auto; PADDING-BOTTOM: 0px; PADDING-TOP: 0px; PADDING-LEFT: 0px; MARGIN: 0px; DISPLAY: block; PADDING-RIGHT: 0px" onkeydown=limitTextArea(this,100,65); onkeyup=limitTextArea(this,100,65); rows=3 cols=10></TEXTAREA>_TA_65_5 </TD>
```

Please help
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change `DISPLAY: block;` to  `DISPLAY: inline;` (2 times). Block elements will always go to a new line...